# Finite extension of a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Is it true, that if $A$ is finitely generated commutatative algebra over a field $k$, not necessary algebraically closed, then prime ideal $p \subset A$ is maximal if and only if $k \subset Quot(A/p)$ is finite extension of fields?

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comment, which was based on a misreading of the question.  My apologies.

Comment: Yes. If $p$ is maximal, then $A/p$ is finite over $k$ by the Nullstellensatz. Conversely, if $A/p$ is finite over $k$, then $A/p$ must be a field, so $p$ is maximal.

Comment: Why finiteness of $Q(A/p)$ implies finiteness of $A/p$?

Comment: This is reduces to a basic fact about integral domains and when finite extensions can be fields.  A basic book on algebra (for example Dummit and Foote) has the references you want.

Comment: Voted to close because this well-known fact is contained in every good introduction to algebraic geometry or commutative algebra - definitely not research level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k\subset Quot(A/p)$ is a finite extension of fields.  Then every nonzero element $x$ of $A/p$ is algebraic over $k$ and so satisfies a minimal polynomial with non-zero constant term $a_0\in k$.  Therefore $x$ divides $a_0$, so $x$ is a unit.

Because every nonzero element of $A/p$ is a unit, $A/p$ is a field, i.e. $p$ is maximal.